# Is there software in Star Trek with a brand name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

What I'm really asking is, in the post-ENT era, are there references to any specific (named) software corporations, brands, packages, or projects?   Are we really supposed to believe that everyone is so unified and committed to the betterment of humanity and the greater UFP culture that everyone uses the same perfect software which only has a generic name?

LCARS is excepted.   It makes sense that there would be a standard OS used by Starfleet.   What tools and OSes do civilians use?   What do people use in their off time?

Comment: Nowhere in the Trek literature are we ever privy to the operating systems used by the Federation. I have watched every episode and read hundreds of books. In the Federation, their software appears to be smart enough to be used everywhere and users spend less time programming like we do today and more time developing concepts that resolve day to day issues. Whatever OS Data uses, it is compatible (where it can be) with Federation technology, and where it isn't, they are forced to learn enough to repair it, as needed.

Comment: I rather liked the title question, but the rest of this is pretty much off-topic - see: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Comment: I feel like this could be tightened up into an acceptable on-topic question, starting by removing the "are we really supposed to believe..." portion - or really the whole second half of it.

Comment: Even with perfect people and perfect software, there would still be *some* diversity due to diversity of uses.  Within current Free Software there is significant, often unnecessary, diversity.  Then there is the fact that most software would be "embedded", practically invisible to the user.  Without a need for artificial barriers (for competition), compatibility would be less difficult tending to blur the distinctions between platforms (OS, software suite); people would be even more inclined than today to say "I was writing a novel" than "I was using MS Word $VERSION to write a novel".

Comment: I think he might do — the emotion chip was the 24th century’s equivalent of installing Facebook Home.

Comment: @phantom42:   Edit away!   No offense taken.

Comment: I would leave closed, but definitely worth an edit.

Comment: I have one example, sort of.  I'll post it if this is reopened.

Comment: Come on everyone -- there's nothing inherently wrong with the question.

Comment: Not only is there only a single OS, it is galaxy wide.  Ever notice how similar almost all ships we see are? Their configurations, their control panels, and their computer systems... the differences are superficial, like different skins or desktop themes.

Comment: If they used money on the Enterprise, you can bet it would be running COBOL.

Comment: The original question had "Does Data run Android OS?" as the joking title.   This got downvoted to heck.   I'm still hurt.

Comment: Do we see any corporate anything? Other than the Ferengi (Sluggo Cola comes to mind) I don't think we see any corporate branded anything. Who makes photon torpedos? Medical scanners? Industrial Replicators? Stem bolts? The cups on Quark's bar? Chalk this one up to Roddenberry's somewhat socialist views of how the world should be. It's also another side effect of the whole "there is no cash in the 24th century".

Comment: @Bachrach44:   Quark's?   Chronowerx?

Comment: @Bachrach44:   YES!  [Broht & Forrester](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Broht_%26_Forrester)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Chronowerx is a 20th century company - doesn't count. (Similarly to Brynner Information Systems - it's from the past as far as trek is concerned even if it's the future to us). Quark's is just the name of a bar (and again, The Ferengi have corporations). Broht & Forrester may be the only corp mentioned by name in trek that's federation based.

Answer (score 5):

I can only think of a handful of cases. In Voyager's "Author, Author", it's mentioned that people [publish holodeck programs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broht_%26_Forrester) for money, usually in the form of stories. Quark mentions that other companies do this as well. I guess this would be the spiritual successor of modern game companies.

Sorry, this is all I've got.

Comment: Does the episode mention money?

Comment: It doesn't. However, it does mention gambling.

Comment: I'm uncertain whether an interactive holo-novel counts as software, any more than my writing this comment is software

Comment: The holonovels count as software because they're interactive. You need to program AI, environmental logic, and other stuff. It's basically like programming in a modern videogame. Somewhere in the captain proton program, there is code like this:

environment.on("anything",function(event){

   constanceGoodheart.screamAt(event);

});

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my recollection there are no specific in-universe references to any branded software. Roddenberry was quite clear that in the future there is no capitalism, hence no brands ([product placement](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Product_placement) notwithstanding)

Out-of-universe, however, you can clearly see that LCARS is in running on Microsoft™ Windows™.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the novel *Cold Equations: The Persistence of Memory*, Dr Soong writes his software for gambling machines which monitors the bio-signs of the participants and manipulates the game depending on the read-outs to make the maximum profit.  It strikes me as somewhat unlikely that Starfleet would allow LCARS to be used for gambling ventures...

In the same book, Dr Soong also details how he worked for Starfleet writing his own security software for them (and left back doors for himself).

All the software which he wrote for the Soong-type androids is evidently compatible with LCARS, possibly built on it, but is his own (and Juliana's) software.

Whether you want to call this software 'Soongian' brand software or not, it's up to you, but there **definitely are people who independently write software that isn't built on independent software that is *not* LCARS**.

The other aspect to remember is that **we are only focusing on the Federation!**  What about all the other computing systems that the other governments use.  What about the *Ferengi*?  In the extreme capitalist society they are, there probably are competing proprietary software brands there.  We also know for a fact that the Klingons, Cardassians and Romulans all use different software systems than the Federation, meaning there is also potential there for brands to creep in there.